# Rename files using regex to delete part of name

Tags: files, regular-expression, rename

I have a bunch of files that I have to process on a Linux machine. The files look like this:

```
2009-08-18T034353_DR1_4N-NAC_123456_1234_band1.ntf          
2009-08-18T034353_DR1_4N-NAC_123456_1234_browse.jpg    
2009-08-18T034353_DR1_4N-NAC_123456_1234_band2.ntf    
2009-08-18T034353_DR1_4N-NAC_123456_1234_license.txt    
2009-08-18T034353_DR1_4N-NAC_123456_1234_metadata.xml     
2009-08-18T034353_DR1_4N-NAC_123456_1234_readme.txt      
2009-08-18T034353_DR1_4N-NAC_123456_1234_udm.tif
```

I want to delete this part: `-NAC_123456_1234` where the first part can consist of alphanumeric characters and the number parts only of numeric characters.

I tried a rename command but couldn't get it to work. I thought of something like:

```
rename '/-[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+//' *.*
```

Can someone help me with what I am missing?

My rename version is:

```
rename from util-linux 2.23.2
```

Comment: I'm afraid the syntax you are trying to use requires Perl `rename`, it isn't supported by the `util-linux` flavor of `rename`. Even then, you would be missing the `s` command before the regex.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Usind CentOS Linux

Comment: OK, in that case you should be able to install `perl-rename`.

Comment: Okay i should have stated that i dont have permissions to install new packages. So that wont be an option.

Comment: `rename` can be downloaded as a standalone script. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you tried to use is for the perl `rename` command. Depending on your operating system, that might be available or installable as `prename` or `perl-rename`, but you want that one and *not* the `rename` from `util-linux` to use the regular expression syntax you were trying. And, even with those, you would need something slightly different:

```
perl-rename 's/-[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+//' *.*
```

Actually, since all you want is to remove everything after the last `-`, you could just use:

```
perl-rename 's/(.*)-(.*)(\.*)/$1$2/' *.*
```

You don't need to use this tool though. You can just run a little shell loop:

```
for file in *; do
    ext="${file##*.}"
    newName="${file%-*}.$ext"
    echo mv -- "$file" "$newName"
done
```

That will just print the commands that will be run. If you are satisfied they are correct, remove the `echo` and run again to actually rename.

#### Explanation

- `for file in *`: will iterate over all files (and directories) in the current directory, saving each as `$file`.
- `ext="${file##*.}"`: the syntax `${variable##pattern}` removes the longest match of `pattern` from the beginning of `$variable`. So here, that will remove everything until the last `.`, leaving us with the file's extension.
- `newName="${file%-*}.$ext"`: the syntax `${variable%pattern}` removes the shortest match of `pattern` from the end of `$variable`. So here, that will leave us with everything until the last `-`. We then add the extension to that and that gives us the new file name.
- `mv -- "$file" "$newName"`: renames the file.

Comment: Okay it goes into the right direction, had one mistake in my first regex, since i want to keep the part after the last "_". I think the + at the end was wront...

Comment: Okay changed the shell loop to:

```for file in *; do
    ext="${file##*_}"
    newName="${file%-*}_$ext"
    echo mv -- "$file" "$newName"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `zsh`, that would be more easily and safely (and portably) done there:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(*-)[[:alnum:]]##_<->_<->(*.*)' '$1$2'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

That's using shell globs (zsh ones with `extendedglob` enabled) instead of regular expressions though in terms of functionality you get the equivalent of extended regexps and more.

- `*` is the usual matches any number of characters (or bytes if there are bytes not forming valid characters, one reason it's safer than (most) regexps
- `[[:alnum:]]` is the standard matching by POSIX character class.
- `##` is one or more of previous atom (like `+` in ERE/PCRE).
- `<->` is any sequence of one or more ASCII decimal digits, like `<1-10>` but without bound.

`zmv` will do a few sanity checks before starting the renaming making it safer than the various variants of `rename` around.